# How can I have a Terraform output become a permanent value in a userdata script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is - but I want to deploy EFS and an ASG + Launch Template with Terraform. I'd like my userdata script (in my launch template) to run commands to mount to EFS

For example:

```
sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-0b28edbb9efe91c25:/ efs
```

My issue is: I need my userdata script to receive my EFS ID, however, this can't just happen on my initial deploy, I also need this to happen whenever I perform a rolling update. I want to be able to change the AMI ID in my launch template, which will perform a rolling update when I run `terraform apply` and need my EFS ID to be in my userdata script to run the command to mount EFS.

Is there a way to have a terraform output get permanently added to my Userdata script? What are other alternatives for making this happen? Would it involve Cloudformation or other AWS services?

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_vpc" "mtc_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.123.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  tags = {
    Name = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "foobar" {
  name_prefix   = "LTTest"
  image_id      = "ami-017c001a88dd93847"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  update_default_version = true

  key_name = "lttest"

  user_data = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/userdata.sh", {efs_id = aws_efs_file_system.foo.id}))

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.test_profile.name
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.mtc_sg.id]
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
  desired_capacity   = 2
  max_size           = 2
  min_size           = 2

  vpc_zone_identifier  = [
    aws_subnet.mtc_public_subnet1.id
    ]

  instance_refresh {
    strategy = "Rolling"
    preferences {
      min_healthy_percentage = 50
    }
  }

  launch_template {
    id      = "${aws_launch_template.foobar.id}"
    version = aws_launch_template.foobar.latest_version
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_file_system" "foo" {
  creation_token   = "jira-efs"
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "alpha" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.foo.id
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.mtc_public_subnet1.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.mtc_sg.id]
}
```

**Update:**

User-data Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo yum install -y amazon-efs-utils

sudo yum install -y git

cd /home/ec2-user
mkdir efs

sudo mount -t efs -o tls ${efs_id}:/ efs
```

Comment: Do you have any TF code to show what is your issue actually? Any errors?

Comment: Which AMI are you using? Custom or AWS provided?

Comment: @MarkoE AL2 Kernel 5.10 - I made the changes Ben suggest and added my TF code and userdata with those changes to the post. It seems like the command to mount EFS in my userdata script isn't working, because when I SSH into my instance and run that command, it mounts EFS instead of saying `/home/ec2-user/efs is already mounted, please run 'mount' command to verify` which would mean that the UD script worked and it's already mounted

Comment: Have you checked this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-mount-helper.html?

Comment: @MarkoE I think that's what I've been going off of- I have my userdata script install the amazon-efs-utils package (It says it's baked into the AL2 AMI, but I got an error because it wasn't installed and the solution I found on here was to install it) and then I run the `sudo mount -t efs -o tls <insert EFS ID>:/ efs` command which is what I want to get my UD script to do. Is there a different way to automate it?

Comment: Does your VPC have DNS hostnames enabled?

Comment: @MarkoE It does not, should I enable them and give the UD script a try?

Comment: I think that is one of the prerequisites for this to work: `VPC has DNS hostnames enabled` -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-mount-helper.html#mount-helper-prerequisites

Comment: @MarkoE Apologies I actually had it enabled, I just added my VPC resource block to the post as well

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Can you check what is inside of the logs: `/var/log/amazon/efs`?

Comment: @MarkoE I ran `sudo vim /var/log/amazon/efs` and it's a weird format but all I see is `mount.log`. 

After I manually run the command to mount `mount-watchdog.log` also shows up in there

Comment: Ok, but is there anything inside that could help you identify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. A couple that come to mind are:

1. Provide the EFS ID to the user data script using the `templatefile()` function.
2. Give your EC2 instance permissions (via IAM) to use the EFS API to search for the ID.

The first option is probably the most practical.

First, define your EFS filesystem (and associated `aws_efs_mount_target` and `aws_efs_access_point` resources, but I'll omit those here):

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {}
```

Now you can define the user data with the `templatefile()` function:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "foo" {
  # ... all the attributes ...

  user_data = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/user-data.sh.tpl", {
    efs_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id # Use dns_name or id here
  })) 
}
```

The contents of `user-data.sh.tpl` can have all your set up steps, including the filesystem mount:

```
sudo mount -t efs -o tls ${efs_id}:/ efs
```

When Terraform renders the user data in the launch template, it will substitute the variable.

Comment: I updated the post and added my user-data script, it doesn't seem to be mounting when the script runs. I SSH'd into my instance and ran `sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-03ac6fdca28d12fcd:/ efs` which is my EFS ID and that's when it mounted. How could I debug this and figure out why that part of the script to mount it isn't working?